# With python sqlite3 module, how to deal with fields that contain double-quotes?

Tags: python, string, sqlite, double-quotes

I was trying to access a database that has data that contains "" such as:

> Tom "is" a cat.

When I use this code:

> myData = 100; myKey = 'Tom "is" a cat.'
>
> myCursor.execute('UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = %d WHERE MyTable.Key ==
>   "%s"' % (myData, myKey))

I got this error

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "is": syntax error

Note that I've enclosed my %s with "".
I've also tried to use single-quotes around it or adding \, neither worked.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: No, no, no! Never ever use the `%` operator to put variables in a SQL statement! Use parameter substitution, like in mouad's answer. You *will not* get the escaping right with `%` – and if you would, it'd take so much more work than using a comma. Seriously. Don't use `%` for SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Use [DB-API parameter substitution](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) and leave the formatting to sqlite3 library:

```
myCursor.execute('UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = ? WHERE MyTable.Key == ?', (myData, myKey))
```

Answer (score -2):

You should not use double quote for surrounding strings in sql statement, thus you should use single quote in the statement:

```
myData = 100 
myKey = 'Tom "is" a cat.'
myCursor.execute('''UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = %d WHERE MyTable.Key ='%s' ''' % (myData, myKey))
```

Triple single quote allows you to use single quotes as if you are in a text editor.

Comment: -1. You should use parameter substitution, not string interpolation, for SQL statements.

Comment: Well, it also works this way; it's an alternative way to do it.

Comment: It's a [very dangerous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) way to do it that you should *not* be teaching to beginners.

Comment: You are absolutely right but using single quotes for strings one of the basics of SQL syntax. I think beginners first should have been thought that.

Comment: It's not a matter of basics order of learning. Putting data strings directly in SQL is *very bad*. This is the #1 security issue on the web. It's also something that can very easily be avoided, if people are yelled at for doing it and taught how to do it right. I can't *not* downvote an answer that suggests it.